# Creating filter in Tableau that views dataset without outliers or all data (with and without outliers)

Tags: tableau-api

I have a **calculated field** called Outlier Detection:

`IIF([min_dictation_sec]>={ FIXED :AVG([min_dictation_sec])-2*STDEV([min_dictation_sec])} AND [min_dictation_sec]<={ FIXED :AVG([min_dictation_sec])+2*STDEV([min_dictation_sec])}=FALSE, "Outliers", "Not Outliers")`

So this becomes a binary field that is either "Outliers" or "Not Outliers"

I created a **parameter** called "Exclude Outliers" because I'd like to create a dashboard filter that looks like this:

```
case [Exclude Outliers] when "Yes" then [Outlier Detection]="Not Outliers"
when "No" then [Outlier Detection] in ["Outliers", "Not Outliers"]
end
```

For "No" I want it to include all the rows. I want the aggregate of all the data in the dataset, whether or not it is an outlier.

PS - The filter has to be binary Yes or No.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a parameter at all. Just place [Outlier Detection] in the filter shelf.

The filter defaults to show an All option.

[image]

Comment: thanks however "Exclude Outliers" needs to be yes or no.